# How to put a pin on my maps (Google Maps) with url?

Tags: google-maps, url, mymaps

I'd like to create a link to place in Google Maps with pin. The whole problem is that I can do this with default map from Google Maps

```
https://www.google.pl/maps/search/?api=1&query=50.942082,17.265832
```

But I can't do the same with my personal created map, I can only view my map centered at this point but without a pin.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/1/viewer?mid=1BTrDLSeOU2BOkc8dfbNaqxVHdNOn70Cl&ll=50.942082%2C17.265832&z=17
```

Is it even possible? I try to add "q" parameter but with no results. No pin is shown. It is very important to me to see exactly where this point is on my background map.

Comment: Consider using [Google Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro), I'll show an example below.
Please note that you'll need to obtain an API key for this.

Answer (score 1):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&key=YOUR_API_KEY

The URL above will show 3 markers and each marker has its own label and color assigned.